# WinRT/C++ What is apartment_context actually?

Tags: c++-winrt, winrt-async

What I know is that `apartment_context` is used to capture UI Thread and return to the UI Thread when it is in the background ThreadPool.

So, what is `apartment_context` actually in WinRT/C++? And how to use it properly and correctly? Then, is this object only able to capture UI Thread?

Finally, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using `apartment_context` compared to `resume_foreground()` and `CoreDispatcher::RunAsync()`?

Thanks

Comment: You could take a look at this document:[Programming with thread affinity in mind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind). It contains the sample code about how to use `apartment_context`

Comment: @Roy Li - MSFT I've read those webs and similar, but I still don't really understand the explanation given on the web. It seems that what I need are some examples of the use of `apartment_context` which is quite complex and under various conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`winrt::apartment_context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/apartment-context)

> captures the thread context within a coroutine so that it can be restored later. You instantiate a **winrt::apartment_context** value, and then later you `co_await` it.

In other words, it allows client code to store information about the *current* thread's apartment, switch to another apartment, and later return to it. It can be constructed on any thread, not just UI threads. However, since UI threads live in the special<sup>1</sup> ASTA (Application Single-Threaded Apartment) and objects owned by those threads frequently have thread-affinity, `apartment_context` is primarily used with UI threads.

The implementation wraps an [`IContextCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ctxtcall/nn-ctxtcall-icontextcallback) interface captured from a call to [`CoGetObjectContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cogetobjectcontext). Its [`ContextCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ctxtcall/nf-ctxtcall-icontextcallback-contextcallback) method

> enters the object context, executes the specified function, and returns.

This is fairly advanced with little to no official documentation available. Luckily, Raymond Chen has published two blog entries<sup>2,3</sup> that cover this area in sufficient detail.

The interface of `apartment_context`, by contrast, doesn't expose any of that complexity. It consists of a default constructor, and the three members `await_ready()`, `await_suspend()`, and `await_resume()` that make it a [coroutine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) awaiter<sup>4</sup>. Consequently, the only operations client code performs is to construct, and `co_await` it. Examples and explanations can be found at [Programming with thread affinity in mind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind).

As for advantages and disadvantages, it comes down to understanding what's going on. While `apartment_context` works as advertised, it's important to keep in mind, that it captures the *current* context. As such, whether a coroutine works as desired becomes a liability of the caller. If (part of) a coroutine needs to execute on the UI thread, it's more robust to use [`resume_foreground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/resume-foreground), and more readable, too. The only downside here is that you need access to a dispatcher.

Finally, [`CoreDispatcher::RunAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) ultimately does the same thing. Except, it's part of the Windows Runtime, whereas `resume_foreground()` is part of the C++/WinRT library. I'm not aware of any functional differences.

---

<sup>1</sup> *[What is so special about the Application STA?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210224-00/?p=104901)*

<sup>2</sup> *[How do you get into a context via `IContext­Callback::Context­allback`?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191128-00/?p=103157)*

<sup>3</sup> *[Using contexts to return to a COM apartment later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191129-00/?p=103162)*

<sup>4</sup> *[C++ Coroutines: Understanding operator co_await](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/11/17/understanding-operator-co-await)*

Comment: Thanks again. This is really very helpful.